# how does "detectLargestObject" work, it's parameters in case of face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I have been working on Face detection using opencv, C++ Eclipse. I got some problem with a program which is as

```
Rect faceRect;    
// Stores the result of the detection, or -1.   
int scaledWidth = 320; // Shrink the image before detection.    
detectLargestObject(cameraImg, faceDetector, faceRect, scaledWidth);    
if (faceRect.width > 0)    
   cout << "We detected a face!" << endl;
```

I don't know what does these parameters indicate in case of "detectLargestObject". Specially, "faceRect". I need some help. Please guide me appropriately as I am new to OpenCV.

Comment: that's from one of the samples, right ? but please, either show more code, or at least a link to the  src you're referring to

Comment: yes, i got this one from Mastering Opencv book, Chapter8. I don't have any other source code, just trying to implement the code in the book. I guess, there is no such opencv function as detectlargestobject...so can u please help me...i want to extract the detected face from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  code for the book is here: https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code

Answer (score 0):

There is no `detectLargestObject` method that is part of OpenCV.
What you got is a custom method that someone implemented, presumably using OpenCV.
What it does depends on where you got the code.

But from the snippet you posted, specifically the comment "`// Stores the result of the detection, or -1.`", faceRect  is an out parameter and will contain the bounding rectangle of the found object after the method has been executed. scaledWidth is the width that the image will be scaled to before detection is performed

Comment: Ok, got it. actually I am referring to Mastering Opencv. And I just want to display a rectangle around the face detected and further extract the part of image inside the rectangle to process it. Can u plz help